# @IBDesignable class with .xib-File not rendering in Interface Builder

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, ibdesignable

I have a `CustomClass.swift` and a `CustomClass.xib`. I want XCode's Interface Builder to render views of class `CustomClass` using the provided .xib-File. Just like it does when I run the app.

I am using XCode **8.3.2 (8E2002)**

### CustomClass.swift

```
import UIKit


@IBDesignable class forceInterface: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("forceInterface", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.frame = self.bounds

    }



    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

    }
}
```

### CustomClass.xib

File owner is set to `CustomClass`. It contains a `UIView` that contains a `UISwitch` and a `UILabel`.
[image: CustomClass.xib]

The problem is that, eventhough I have `@IBDesignable` in my `CustomClass.swift`, it isn't rendering in the InterfaceBuilder. I am placing a `UIView` there and setting its class to `CustomClass`:
[image]

As you can see, it even says *Designables: Up to date* in the inspector. But I am not seeing anything.

**When running the app everything works as expected!**

Comment: Each ibdesignable have only 200ms to render it on storyboard, if componet failed to render in 200ms then you will get warning in warning tab(4th left panel).

Comment: There is **no warning**. Yet the component does not render.

Comment: @Marmelador What do you mean by "rendering in the InterfaceBuilder"

Comment: I want XCode's Interface Builder to render views of class `CustomClass` using the provided .xib-File. Just like it does when I run the app.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? If so, what did you do?

Comment: I eventually got it to work in another project. So I suggest starting in a clean project would help with tracking down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this

```
self.addSubview(view)
view.frame = self.bounds
```

You should assign the views' frame before you add it as a subview to its superview

```
view.frame = self.bounds
self.addSubview(view)
```

I am not sure why you view is not loading even though you have assigned it as IBDesignable. I normally use these steps to troubleshoot.

- Close and reopen Xcode
- Clean Xcode
- Wait for a while, normally around a minute or so, and you will see the view refresh/update itself, displaying your custom drawn content